# Time-dependence of PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $u = u(t,(x,y))$,

$$\alpha\frac{\partial u}{\partial t } + \mathbf{v}\cdot \nabla u - \nabla \cdot [D(u)\nabla u ] =0 \text{ in } \Omega, t>0$$

with Dirichlet boundary condition $u=g(x,y)$ on $\partial \Omega$, $t>0$ and initial condition $u(0,(x,y))=u_0(x,y)$.

It is stated that if $\alpha = 0$ the problem is time independent. This confuses me, because the solution is defined to be also a function of $t$, setting $\alpha$ equal to zero does not exclude the option that $u$ is time dependent right?

Comment: it may be a constant function of t, like f(x) = 5 is also a function of x?

Comment: Ah so you mean to have a unique solution, $u$ can't depend on $t$?

Comment: @Keeponcruising. Yes, the PDE shows no dependence on time, or the solution is time invariant